# I want to start my activity on a predifined time. For example 3 o'clock

Tags: android

Whats wrong in Code?
I have changed the time to just test.
Please provide the result in detail.

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SEDate futureDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 86400000);
    futureDate.setHours(7);
    futureDate.setMinutes(45);
    futureDate.setSeconds(0);

    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyBroadcastReceiver.class);

    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0,intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

This is My Broadcast Reciever

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
//MediaPlayer mp;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //mp=MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.alrm   );
    //mp.start();
    //Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent scheduledIntent = new Intent(context, HorrorRes.class);
    scheduledIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(scheduledIntent);

}
}
```

Comment: Where are you setting the alarm? That is, where are you calling `am.set()`, or a similar method?

Comment: Why are you doing new Date().getTime() + 86400000 which is going to get the current time and then add that period.. and then set the calendar time params after that.. you shoudl set the data first.. then set it

Answer (score 1):

I have a lot of wisdom specifically for what you aim to achieve. I have recently published an Alarm Clock app which may only be disabled via NFC (tap-and-pay) technology.

Here are a few things you will need to do going forward:

- Use getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
- Calendar is VERY particular. Use Calendar .add() or .set() and the calendar class will change many of its internal variables appropriately.Use Calendar.getTime() will recompute all of Calendar's inner fields and then return your Date object.

  ```
  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
  calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 4);
  Date date = calendar.getTime();
  Log.d("WakefulReceiver", date.toString());
  mAlarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,    date.getTime(), mIntent);
  ```
- Your Intent is looks fine.
- Transition your BroadcastReceiver to being a WakefulBroadcastReceiver, this class handles your wakelock and does the heavy lifting for you. We really just want a BroadcastReceiver in Android to receive(). In the receive you can start an IntentService.
- IntentService will be the class to handle the multiple things which should happen by your design. Your IntentService should: (A) start a separate service to run an Async Foreground Media Player. (B) start your activity.

I can get into much more detail, [here is my Github project code.](https://github.com/apelsoczi/NFCAlarm/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/adam/nfcalarm)

- WakefulBroadcastReceiver = /app/WakefulReceiver.java
- IntentService = /app/RingingService.java
- MediaPlayer (as a Foreground Async Service) = /app/AlarmService.java

**Message me for more insight!**

Comment: What is meant by mIntent and nAlarmManager

Comment: I have a lot of questions regarding code        how can I contact you     I am new at StackOverflow